# tabview column according to screen size

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> I have a table

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/branchTable"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/EditTextSubHeading"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:collapseColumns="30sp" >
</TableLayout>
```

> I want to fit all column according to screen size.Mean if I have a Tab
>   10.1" and I have 5 column each column should take 10.1" / 5

Answer (score 0):

try `android:layout_span="value"`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_span

you can also try `android:layout_column="value"`

tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your tablelayout:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
```

It means all columns are able to shrink and stretch. Android will handle how to allocate nice space for all columns. You can also specify which columns you want to strech or shrink as well, by setting numbers in the above code.